# How to create content rotator/slider in WPF using ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

My goal is to create a content slider with WPF similar to what is widely available using JQuery. An example is the Moving boxes script:
[Moving Boxes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/)

I've been searching, but it's hard to find when WPF has a control called Slider, and Rotator is usually referencing animation.  I've tried using a horizontal stackpanel inside of a custom animated scrollviewer to little success. So any ideas are appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I was able to accomplish this functionality by creating a custom ScrollViewer control with dependency properties added to enable animation of the scrolling via events.  I used this project as inspiration:[Animate WPF ScrollViewer on Codeplex](http://aniscrollviewer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Have it worked? Im looking for the same. can u share the code?

Answer (score 0):

I done something similar to this a while ago but I haven't got the code anymore.

I am sure I used a listview on a stackpanel with horizontal orientation and you are able to hide the scroll bar so it just looks like a plain list.

You can then create two controls for scrolling left or right and when either is pressed just call the scrollIntoView method of the Listview object.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: that's something I haven't looked into. I'll go down that path now and see how it works out.

Comment: Good luck mate. I got it working but it was at my old job so I can't even magic the code up for you. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link on the subject http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/06/a-carousel-view-for-elementflow/ it's a 3d control but it can give you some ideas